# Codeigniter not handling question mark in Instagram auth redirect

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, instagram, codeigniter-3

On my website I allow users to link their social media accounts but I have the users authenticate themselves first via the social media API before I add their username.

I am using the Instagram auth api in sandbox mode on my public site (not localhost)   and sending the auth request is not an issue but the redirct code from Instagram includes a question mark and I cannot properly parse the URI segments because of this, nothing is showing up in URI segments after the question mark. Below are my settings.

The URL to Instagram is https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=7e9b6fabc5bb49e28d24e32a3232380b&redirect_uri=https://www.mywebsite.com/ig/complete&response_type=code.

The redirect URL is https://www.mywebsite.com/ig/complete?code=def1efc5f494483a9286b2136e644999

My route is as follows:

```
$route['ig/complete?(.+)'] = "callback/ig_handle_response/$1";
```

My cofig allowed characters are as follows:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-+?';
```

When I print_r the segments array, the output is **Array( [1] => ig [2] => complete )**, the URI segments do not contain the code returned from Instagram, looks like anything after the question mark is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue myself by getting the query_string from the URL.

```
$code = $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING', TRUE);
```

Result of $code is "code=83339246a9c74501b9ffafe65aa222ff"